# Migrate web2py tables to mysql

Tags: python-3.x, web2py

I am new in `web2py` and try to migrate all tables from `sqlite` to `mysql` or export tables to `sql` format.

Answer (score 0):

The web2py DAL provides a mechanism for exporting all tables into a CSV file (`db.export_to_csv_file()`) and then importing that CSV file to populate a new database (`db.import_from_csv_file()`), as detailed [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#CSV--all-tables-at-once-).